# Shorthand for importing a function from a nested module

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

### Question

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
└── main_module
    ├── __init__.py # init1
    └── my_module
        └── __init__.py # init2
        └──my_module
            └── __init__.py # init3
            └── file1.py (with awesome_func())
            └── file2.py
```

I would like to import `awesome_func()` from `file1.py` like this:

```
from main_module.my_module.file1 import awesome_func
```

so that I don't have to repeat `my_module` like this:

```
from main_module.my_module.my_module import awesome_func
```

### My (failed) approach

I tried e.g. modifying `init2` like this:

```
from .my_module import file1
```

which allows me to do this:

```
from main_module.my_module import file1
file1.awesome_func()
```

but have not figured out a way to do what I originally intended:

```
from main_module.my_module.file1 import awesome_func
```

Running the line above currently yields:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_module.my_module.file1'

I guess I need to modify too `init3`, but I am not sure how.

Comment: why do you have two `my_module` folders? I'm curious to know.

Comment: @FarhoodET Because it's a monolithic repo, where the first `my_module` is more of a root directory for my package, while the second `my_module` is really where I have the source code. In the first level I have e.g. `requirements`, `README` and such.

Answer (score 0):

use `__all__` in `__init__`3 and import file1.py as

```
from . import file1
__all_ = ['file1']
```

in `__init__` 2 do

```
from .my_module import *

__all__ = ['file1']`
```

this will do the desired import way

Comment: @LukaszTracewski try reading on `__all__` functionlity in python, this will help you for sure